# jquery select checkbox by div

Tags: jquery

I'm wondering if there is a way in jQuery to check/uncheck a checkbox when someone clicks an entire div layer. Like having a massive selection area, essentially.

Any ideas?

Here is an example... I am trying to make the  around the checkbox clickable to toggle the individual checkbox, pretty much.

```
<fieldset>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox1" />
    </div>
    Person 1<br />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <div >
        <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox2" />
    </div>
    Person 2<br />
</fieldset>
```

Comment: The obvious and most semantic way to do this is to use a label element instead of a div with the label's 'for' attribute set to the checkbox's id--no JavaScript necessary! The only caveat is that label is an inline element so it can't contain block elements. If you only want to put inline elements inside the div, use label instead. Otherwise eyazici's answer should work.

Comment: Do you want to check a single box when clicking several other things, or check many boxes when clicking a single thing?

Comment: Single checkbox clicking a single thing, repetitive. I want to make a list of cards, each one having a checkbox. The header of the card will be clickable and will 'check' it, essentially.

Comment: I have updated the question with a clearer example. I apologize for the lack of information.

Comment: you can make the label contain block level elements using CSS - if you put a span in the label and style it : display:block;

Comment: matpol, I'm not sure I understand. So if I make the div use display:block, it will just inherit it's underlying checkbox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps use the clicked div as the parent.

```
$(function() {
     $('#divId').toggle(
       function(event) {
         $(this).find('input').attr('checked', true);
       },
       function(event) {
         $(this).find('input').attr('checked', false);
       }
     );
 });
```

This should only check the boxes inside the #divId that's clicked.

Comment: Yes! I believe that did it! Can I bother for any information on what is going on here so I can understand it better?

Comment: It's the same as Aaron's response, but instead of a global $('input') ("find all inputs in the document"), I limit it to the div ("this") that was clicked ("find all inputs inside "the clicked div")

Answer (score 6):

```
$('fieldset div').bind('click', function() {
    var checkbox = $(this).find(':checkbox');

    checkbox.attr('checked', !checkbox.attr('checked'));
});
```

Comment: This also worked. Thank you all so much! I'm learning more about jQuery with each new thing I get to try.

Answer (score 4):

When you want to make this work both to click on the div and input inside it, and also trigger change function, you can use following code:

```
$('input').change(function() {
    console.log('change triggered')
}).click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation()
})

$('div').click(function() {
    var c = $this.find('input')
    c.attr('checked', (!c.is(':checked')).change()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your check all checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" /> Check All
```

And your JS code:

```
  $('#checkAll').click(function() {
        if($(this).attr('checked')) {
            $('input:checkbox').attr('checked', false);
        } else {
            $('input:checkbox').attr('checked', true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Er, I don't think that does what I'm trying to do. I only want to check one box at a time if a larger layer around it is clicked. Not all of them. If I use that as an ID, I can only put it on one checkbox.

Comment: No, I'm sorry. This isn't what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
          $('#divId').toggle(
            function(event) {
              $('input[name=foo]').attr('checked', true);
            },
            function(event) {
              $('input[name=foo]').attr('checked', false);
            }
          );
      });
```

Comment: This is close, but it still checks everything on the page. The contents are being generated from a database, and there are dozens on the same page.