# Checkbox/radiobox style for IE7+

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I hate IE7, it makes me ill. Please I need help with this, probably I am doing something wrong or ...

This is my css:

```
input[type='checkbox'] 
{
    opacity: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 18px;
}
input[type='checkbox'] + label {
    margin: 0;
    clear: none;
    padding: 5px 0 4px 24px;
    /* Make look clickable because they are */
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(https://css-tricks.com/wufoo/themes/customradiosandcheckboxes/off.png) left center no-repeat;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked + label {
    background-image: url(https://css-tricks.com/wufoo/themes/customradiosandcheckboxes/check.png);
```

html:

```
<input id="Field2" name="Field2" type="checkbox" class="field checkbox" checked="checked">
<label class="choice" for="Field2">First Choice</label>
<br><br>
<input id="Field3" name="Field3" type="checkbox" class="field checkbox">
<label class="choice" for="Field3">Second Choice</label>
<br><br>
<input id="Field4" name="Field4" type="checkbox" class="field checkbox">
<label class="choice" for="Field4">Third Choice</label></body>
```

IE9 view:

[image]

IE7 & IE8

[image]

I found that someone said that it should work with "selectivizr.js" more detail son this website "http://selectivizr.com/"

I did as they indicated:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="selectivizr.js"></script>
  <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="[fallback css]" /></noscript>
<![endif]-->
```

This didnt fix the problem.

I created this fiddle if someone would like to give a try! http://jsfiddle.net/6mUWk/

Comment: Styling inputs have always been inconsistent across browsers, i'd suggest hiding the input all together and just styling a div that then updates the value of the input behind the scenes.

Comment: Your images didn't come through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all that gived a try!

However the best solution till now i guess is only this which is with the help of jQuery:

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-checkbox/

It is simple and pure clean!!!

I tested it and it supports all browsers that i need!

Answer (score 2):

IE supports `:checked` pseudoclass as of version **9**. Use JavaScript to track state of check field and apply style to a regular class.

Alternatively, use custom form-controls for IE9+ only while using regular form-controls in old IE7/8. Such separation of IE versions can be achieved, for example, with [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes, but that does not fix the visuals for this situation.

Answer (score -1):

Kevin's comment is correct. SELECT, RADIO and CHECKBOX do not behave like standard HTML elements and are rather platform-dependent. A Checkbox on XP will be different than one on Win7 or MACOS.

You may want to consider using a hidden form field and using a JavaScript-based replacement for what you want to do.

Based on: [jquery select checkbox by div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827617/jquery-select-checkbox-by-div)

```
$(function() {
     $('.someWrapper').toggle(
       function(event) {
         $(this).find('input').prop('checked', true);
       },
       function(event) {
         $(this).find('input').prop('checked', false);
       }
     );
 });
```

Comment: Hello! I found similar to what you said here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827617/jquery-select-checkbox-by-div

Comment: That code is incorrect. .attr('checked', true); should be .prop('checked', true);

Comment: Ok I am a bit familiar with jQuery but not a profy. This means if I have 20 Checkboxes i must make 20 functions?

Comment: No, you can use class names. I'll post some code in my answer.

Comment: Please i need help. No one with some example?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r4Tq5/ This auto hides the div with the checkbox... It must be something more